# Adding lines of 2 text files by turns

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a .bat file that is getting 3 parameters - 2 input files and a name for an output file - and writes a new file with the lines of input1 and input2 alternating.

This may sound weird, but I'll try to get in an example:

content of 1.txt:

```
line 1
line 3
line 5
```

content of 2.txt:

```
line 2
line 4
line 6
```

when run as

```
> myscript.bat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

the script should create a file `3.txt` with the content:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
```

- When trying to solve this I encountered the problem that using a `for-loop` with `token=*` only works for a single file, not for two.
- Using 2 nested for-loops results in the first line of 1.txt and the whole content of 2.txt to be saved in 3.txt, followed by the second line of 1.txt and again the whole content of 2.txt and so on until the last line of 1.txt is appended to 3.txt (followed by the content of 2.txt again).

How could I achieve to alternate the lines?

Greetings, Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will have trouble if any of your lines have exclamation points in them, none of the lines can be longer than 8192 characters, and if the second file is shorter than the first file, it will only use as many lines from the first file as there in the second file (if file1.txt has 5 lines and file2.txt has three lines, the script will only take the first 3 lines from file1.txt and the output will have 6 lines total), but the code works otherwise:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set file1=%~1
set file2=%~2
set target_file="%~3"

:: Read in the entire first file and store it in an arraylike
set counter=-1
for /f "delims=" %%A in (%file1%) do (
    set /a counter=!counter!+1
    set file_1[!counter!]=%%A
)

:: Read in the entire second file and store it in an arraylike
set counter=-1
for /f "delims=" %%A in (%file2%) do (
    set /a counter=!counter!+1
    set file_2[!counter!]=%%A
)

:: Read one line at a time, alternating lines
type nul>%target_file%
for /L %%A in (0,1,!counter!) do (
    echo !file_1[%%A]!>>%target_file%
    echo !file_2[%%A]!>>%target_file%
)
```

Comment: Is this solution also limited to a maximum character amount of 1021 like in Dave's solution? Because if not I would prefer this one over his solution due to the kinda low limit of characters. Will try it out tomorrow!

Comment: Changed my mind and tested it right away. Your script works perfectly fine and does exactly what it should, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure native batch solution.

- File 1 lines are limited to a bit less than 8191 bytes long.
- File 2 lines are limited to 1021 bytes long, and trailing control characters are stripped
- Empty lines and exclamation points are preserved in both files

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
<test2.txt >out.txt (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "test1.txt"') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:*:=!
    set "ln="
    set /p "ln="
    echo(!ln!
    endlocal
  )
)
```

There is a much simpler, faster, and more robust solution with no limitations using my [JREPL.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a hybrid JScript/batch script that runs on any Windows machine from XP onward.

JREPL.BAT is designed to do regular expression search and replace on file content, which is not what you need. However, it has the ability to read from both stdin and a file, so it is a convenient way to merge the contents of two files without writing much code.

The following assumes file 1 has at least as many lines as file 2.

```
type test1.txt|jrepl "^" "" /jendln "stdout.WriteLine(stdin.ReadLine())" /f test2.txt /o out.txt
```

You haven't stated what to do if one file has more lines than the other. Either of the solutions above could be modified to suit your needs if this can happen.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot to mention that both files definitely have the same amount of lines. I'll try out your solution tomorrow (2am in my time zone already...)